# 3d Plot from Dictionary of Tuples List

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, tuples

I would like to create a plot from a dictionary containing keys with value: a list of tuples. Each tuple contains a distance and ontime pair. I show 4 of the 279 below.

In []: onTimesAll

```
{'SNR000.0+00.0': [[1, 334108805.6],
[2, 334108805.6],
[3, 334108805.6],
[4, 334108805.6],
[5, 334108805.6],
[6, 334108805.6],
[7, 334108805.6],
[8, 333504005.6],
[9, 332899205.6],
[10, 332899205.6],
[11, 329270405.6],
[12, 328060805.6],
[13, 328060805.6],
[14, 328060805.6],
[15, 328060805.6]],
'SNR000.3+00.0': [[1, 334108805.6],
[2, 334108805.6],
[3, 334108805.6],
[4, 334108805.6],
[5, 334108805.6],
[6, 334108805.6],
[7, 334108805.6],
[8, 334108805.6],
[9, 334108805.6],
[10, 334108805.6],
[11, 334108805.6],
[12, 334108805.6],
[13, 333504005.6],
[14, 331084805.6],
[15, 331084805.6]],
'SNR000.9+00.1': [[1, 334108805.6],
[2, 334108805.6],
[3, 334108805.6],
[4, 334108805.6],
[5, 334108805.6],
[6, 334108805.6],
[7, 334108805.6],
[8, 334108805.6],
[9, 334108805.6],
[10, 334108805.6],
[11, 334108805.6],
[12, 334108805.6],
[13, 332294405.6],
[14, 331084805.6],
[15, 331084805.6]],
'SNR001.0-00.1': [[1, 334108805.6],
[2, 334108805.6],
[3, 334108805.6],
[4, 334108805.6],
[5, 334108805.6],
[6, 334108805.6],
[7, 334108805.6],
[8, 334108805.6],
[9, 334108805.6],
[10, 334108805.6],
[11, 334108805.6],
[12, 334108805.6],
[13, 332294405.6],
[14, 331084805.6],
[15, 331084805.6]]}
```

I would like to create a plot of distance (xaxis) vs (percent) ontime (yaxis) with the color axis showing frequency (number of times a key exists at a point on the plot). I've been able to do this *without* the frequency part, awkwardly, with the following bit of code:

```
snrsAll = onTimesAll.keys()
xlabel('Distance (deg)')
ylabel('Percent Time On (out of 334108805.6 MET)')
pctTimeOn = []
for snr in snrsAll : 
    info = onTimesAll.get(snr)
    dist, time = zip(*info)
    pctT1, pctT2, pctT3, pctT4, pctT5, pctT6, pctT7, pctT8, pctT9, pctT10, pctT11, pctT12, pctT13, pctT14, pctT15 = numpy.array(time)/334108805.6
    pctT = (pctT1, pctT2, pctT3, pctT4, pctT5, pctT6, pctT7, pctT8, pctT9, pctT10, pctT11, pctT12, pctT13, pctT14, pctT15)
    plt.plot(dist, pctT, 'ro')
    pctTimeOn.append(pctT)
```

which produces this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxL31.jpg . What I'd like to be able to show w color is that there are, 4 keys (SNRs) with percent ontime < 100% at a distance of 1deg, 9 at 2deg, etc.

I'm pretty sure there must be a better way to do this and to include the color axis, but even w much googling and trying, I haven't been able to figure it out.

I would then like to be able to easily identify how many and which of my keys have (percent) ontimes less than 100%. So suggestions for efficient ways of searching dict values and returning keys would be really welcome too!

Comment: Could you add an example of how the plot should be done? I don't understand what exactly do you want. Which one is the color axis?

Comment: You can see it here: http://imgur.com/IC6tCd7 .
(Sorry I wasn't allowed to directly attach the plot.)